# Can't SSH as root user, can ssh as regular user?

Tags: linux, ssh

I have a system with Ubuntu Server 18.04.3 (machine1) connecting to a raspberry pi 3B+ running raspbian buster (machine2).

I am setting up something with sshfs.  I am validating the configuration before using sshfs by using regular ssh, and it's not working.  I want to be able to ssh into machine2 from machine1 as user1 on machine2 as user2 on machine1 and as root on machine1.

So:
`user1@machine1: ssh -p 123 user2@machine2`
That works.

`root@machine1: ssh -p 123 user2@machine2`
That doesn't work; I immediately get connection refused and nothing shows up in auth.log on machine2.

I was wondering if it was a .Xsession file thing, but I can't get anything in the debug output.  Both root and user1 on machine1 have rsa keys generated which are in authorized_keys in the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file for user2 on machine2.  If I remove the keys, it's the same thing (I'm not prompted for password).  As far as I can tell, the root attempt doesn't ever leave machine1.

I haven't found anything in machine1's logs.  Any advice is appreciated!  This is /etc/ssh/ssh_config (without comments) on machine1:

```
Host *
    ForwardAgent yes
    ForwardX11 yes
    ForwardX11Trusted yes
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

Edit 1:

There is no ~/.ssh/config file on any host; there is id_rsa and id_rsa.pub on all hosts for all users (my standard practice) and authorized_hosts on machine2 for user2.  user1 and root have known_hosts as well.

Output of requested command:

```
root@machine1:~# ssh -p 123 -vvv user1@machine2
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "machine2" port 123
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to machine2 [machine2] port 123.
debug1: connect to address machine2 port 123: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host machine2 port 123: Connection refused
```

Comment: Do you have `~/.ssh/config` files on `machine1` for `user1` and/or `root` (in the latter case, `/root/.ssh/config` by default). If so, do they have stanzas for `machine2`?

Comment: If you can post it, what is the output of `root@machine1: ssh -vv -p 123 user2@machine2`?

Comment: I updated the post to reflect your questions.